# Is it possible to determine when a message has been entirely read when reading from a Named Pipe in Overlapped I/O?

Tags: winapi, named-pipes, interprocess

It is very easy to determine if a message has been entirely read when reading form a pipe with read mode set to **PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE** in synchronous I/O. (If the ReadFile function returns FALSE and **GetLastError()** returns **ERROR_MORE_DATA**, it means that the message is incomplete and that subsequent reads are necessary to retrieve the full message.)

Now, if the Named Pipe operates in Overlapped I/O instead and a read operation is pending (ReadFile function returns **FALSE** and **GetLastError()** returns **ERROR_IO_PENDING**), how do I know if I retrieved the full message when the operation completes? All I can determine is the number of bytes that were actually transferred by calling the **GetOverlappedResult** function, but it does not tell me whether or not the full message has been read…

Am I missing something here?

Comment: you can bind your pipe iocp, say via `BindIoCompletionCallback` and you got status in callback. or if you bind it to own iocp - you get operation status when call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`.

Comment: I never intentionally got this wrong, but I'm not buying.  Surely you'll still get ERROR_MORE_DATA from GetOverlappedResult.  You'll have to show us your version.

Comment: *GetOverlappedResult function, but it does not tell me whether or not the full message has been read* really tell - it return *false* to you and `GetLastError()` will return `ERROR_MORE_DATA` if message is incomplete readed. if it return true - all is ok.

Comment: @HansPassant, you are right. My mistake...

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way ist to know, how long the messages is that you are expecting. Your protocol may give you the information.

For example the protocol always delivers a WORD as the first 2 bytes that tells you the length of the complete message.

So I use overlapped I/O with `ReadFile` to get the first 2 Bytes of the WORD. When I receive them I use `ReadFile` without overlapped I/O using the known message length and so I get all data.